# "Results found containing ___" too close to header

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, search

Search for [something](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=something),

> [image: example here, on meta]

[anything](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=anything),

> [image: example on a beta site]

[everywhere](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=everywhere)

> [image: but this example is ELU]

[really](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=really)

> [image: and this example is SFF]

and you will see that "results found containing __" is just a little too close to the header. It's not like there isn't [the space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=the+space) to have it be a little lower, closer to "Search":

> [image: found 11,035 results for the space on WB]

---

The UI has been updated since I took the above screenshots, and the text you search for is [bold](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=bold) (which fixes another design issue but not the one in this question):

> [image: Academia results]

Comment: BTW, it looks better on SO, where topbar is different.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: Someone missed some padding or margin, yeah.

Comment: Did they document/ announce anywhere that they'll move that summary from the side bar to the top? Especially when you run long searches, it looks very weird having them not separated by any means; there used to be linebreaks after every option in the side bar. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRBgV.png

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has been fixed (let us know if it isn't displaying properly for you now).

Comment: @Martin no it's not documented anywhere, they sometimes make small changes without telling or announcing. Usually just design, in this case the search logic itself also changed behind the scenes, they added "Did you mean?" module etc.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Tim Post's comment, this is fixed. The text now appears under "Search":

[image: ereh noitpircsed egami retne]