# Search request options should use some kind of separation

Tags: bug, design, search

At least 2 days ago search options were placed on the right side of the page and were separated by new lines.

Now all such options are displayed in one line with wrapping if page width is not enough:

> [image: one line]

Could there please some kind of separator be added?

Also options that are used like key:value pair should not be split on several lines, i.e. non-breakable spaces should be there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Results found containing \_\_\_" too close to header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303536/results-found-containing-too-close-to-header)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling my post about separation between options itself, not between header and text.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I misread.