# Remove “That solved my problem” without editing

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

My [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303545/339911) is wrongly suggested as a duplicate for another one. User who suggested a duplicate already [answer me in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303545/search-request-options-should-use-some-kind-of-separation?noredirect=1#comment987003_303545) that he make it by misreading. Unfortunately I still see “That solved my problem” banner on the top of the post:

> [image: banner]

Is there any way to remove such banner without editing the post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to only hide the notice without doing either of those things. It will get displayed until the duplicate vote no longer exists, either because the user retracted it or it aged away. If they admitted it was wrong, a comment pointing out that they can retract the close vote would probably be beneficial. It would also make sure the question doesn't end up in the Close Votes queue continuing to collect reviews that essentially waste people's time for an incorrect close vote.

Comment: As an aside, in your case it looks like another user already cast a close vote for the same reason, which is why it's a good idea to retract close votes/flags before they become a problem!

Comment: If the question become closed, I will blame that guys who cast close votes in incompetence :)

Comment: @alexolut You could just edit the question.